# WEBFLOW HTML/CSS trouble with putting image into internet explorer only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, explorer, webflow

I've been trying to get an svg animation to only show up in browsers that are not ie 10/11 since it does not show up how I want it to. I was helped with some code that detects the browser, but now i need help putting the svg animation into the code and also putting an image into the only ie 10/11 part of the code.

I've tried copy pasting the svg animation into it but when I do that nothing shows up on ie or chrome. the top part of the code is the animation and the bottom part is the part that detects the browser.

```html
<div> <svg id="isi-wave" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="519 0 2022 1225.25"> <g id="wave"> <path d="M5983.25,234v991.28H0V233.7c8.66.74,17.26,1.13,26,1.52l.23.18C209.57,244,520.63,39,785.09,39c242.62,0,530.06,179.27,710.72,195v-.27c8.66.74,17.26,1.13,26,1.52l.23.18C1705.39,244,2016.44,39,2280.9,39c242.62,0,530.06,179.27,710.72,195v-.27c8.67.74,17.26,1.13,26,1.52l.23.18C3201.2,244,3512.26,39,3776.71,39c242.62,0,530.07,179.27,710.72,195v-.27c8.66.74,17.26,1.13,26,1.52l.23.18C4697,244,5008.07,39,5272.53,39,5515.15,39,5802.6,218.26,5983.25,234Z" fill="#00a6dd"/> <path d="M5983.25,187.32v51C5707.9,230.8,5516.38,86.11,5214.88,86.11c-237.08,0-397.67,115.57-615.18,145-9.24,1.23-18.56,2.35-28,3.23-18.87,1.85-38.17,3-58,3.35h-.23c-30.14.56-21.88.69-26,.62v0c-275.35-7.47-466.86-152.16-768.37-152.16-237.07,0-397.66,115.57-615.17,145-9.25,1.23-18.57,2.35-28,3.23-18.87,1.85-38.16,3-58,3.35h-.23c-30.13.56-21.88.69-25.95.62v0c-275.35-7.47-466.87-152.16-768.37-152.16-237.07,0-397.67,115.57-615.18,145-9.24,1.23-18.56,2.35-28,3.23-18.87,1.85-38.17,3-58,3.35h-.23c-30.13.56-21.88.69-26,.62C1220.45,230.8,1028.94,86.11,727.44,86.11c-237.08,0-397.67,115.57-615.18,145-9.24,1.23-18.56,2.35-28,3.23-18.87,1.85-38.16,3-58,3.35H26c-30.14.56-21.89.69-26,.62v-51c35.7,6.16,50.4,9.7,110.6,9.7C276.1,197,592.14,0,841.93,0c218.51,0,473.38,146.92,653.88,187.32,35.7,6.16,50.4,9.7,110.6,9.7C1771.91,197,2088,0,2337.74,0c218.51,0,473.38,146.92,653.88,187.32h0c35.7,6.16,50.4,9.7,110.6,9.7,165.5,0,481.54-197,731.32-197,218.52,0,473.38,146.92,653.88,187.32v0c35.7,6.16,50.4,9.7,110.6,9.7,165.5,0,481.54-197,731.33-197C5547.88,0,5802.75,146.92,5983.25,187.32Z" fill="#0045ab"/> </g> <g id="bubbles"> <circle id="bubble_1" data-name="bubble 1" cx="707.51" cy="109.89" r="70.69" fill="#fff" opacity="0.57"/> <circle id="bubble_2" data-name="bubble 2" cx="906.53" cy="83.33" r="49.13" fill="#fff" opacity="0.4"/> <circle id="bubble_3" data-name="bubble 3" cx="1267.49" cy="128.73" r="101.27" fill="#fff" opacity="0.35"/> <circle id="bubble_4" data-name="bubble 4" cx="1528.18" cy="88.09" r="61.16" fill="#fff" opacity="0.65"/> <circle id="bubble_5" data-name="bubble 5" cx="1892.64" cy="175.38" r="128.84" fill="#fff" opacity="0.52"/> <circle id="bubble_6" data-name="bubble 6" cx="2081.9" cy="83.86" r="44.87" fill="#fff" opacity="0.56"/> <circle id="bubble_7" data-name="bubble 7" cx="2339.83" cy="103.63" r="76.7" fill="#fff" opacity="0.7"/> </g> <style> #isi-wave #wave { -webkit-animation: moveWave 4s linear 0s infinite; animation: moveWave 4s linear 0s infinite; } #isi-wave #bubble_1 { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 220px); -ms-transform: translate(0px, 220px); transform: translate(0px, 220px); -webkit-animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -1.8s infinite alternate; animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -1.8s infinite alternate; } #isi-wave #bubble_2 { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 200px); -ms-transform: translate(0px, 200px); transform: translate(0px, 200px); -webkit-animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -2.28s infinite alternate; animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -2.28s infinite alternate; } #isi-wave #bubble_3 { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 230px); -ms-transform: translate(0px, 230px); transform: translate(0px, 230px); -webkit-animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -3.2s infinite alternate; animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -3.2s infinite alternate; } #isi-wave #bubble_4 { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 210px); -ms-transform: translate(0px, 210px); transform: translate(0px, 210px); -webkit-animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -3.8s infinite alternate; animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -3.8s infinite alternate; } #isi-wave #bubble_5 { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 210px); -ms-transform: translate(0px, 210px); transform: translate(0px, 210px); -webkit-animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -0.92s infinite alternate; animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -0.92s infinite alternate; } #isi-wave #bubble_6 { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 210px); -ms-transform: translate(0px, 210px); transform: translate(0px, 210px); -webkit-animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -1.32s infinite alternate; animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -1.32s infinite alternate; } #isi-wave #bubble_7 { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 220px); -ms-transform: translate(0px, 220px); transform: translate(0px, 220px); -webkit-animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -2.04s infinite alternate; animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -2.04s infinite alternate; } @-webkit-keyframes moveIn { to { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px); transform: translate(0px, 0px); } } @keyframes moveIn { to { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px); transform: translate(0px, 0px); } } @-webkit-keyframes moveWave { to { -webkit-transform: translate(-1495.81px, 0px); transform: translate(-1495.81px, 0px); } } @keyframes moveWave { to { -webkit-transform: translate(-1495.81px, 0px); transform: translate(-1495.81px, 0px); } } </svg> 
  

<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font: 1.25em sans-serif;
        background-color:white;

    }
    @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
        /* IE10+ specific styles go here */
        body{
            background-color:blue;
            <img alt="" src="https://assets.website-files.com/5d016609a151693900497381/5d1f7a94fd3194c9ef4637c4_Wave%20test.png" 
            srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/5d016609a151693900497381/5d1f7a94fd3194c9ef4637c4_Wave%20test-p-500.png 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/5d016609a151693900497381/5d1f7a94fd3194c9ef4637c4_Wave%20test-p-800.png 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/5d016609a151693900497381/5d1f7a94fd3194c9ef4637c4_Wave%20test-p-1080.png 1080w, https://assets.website-files.com/5d016609a151693900497381/5d1f7a94fd3194c9ef4637c4_Wave%20test-p-1600.png 1600w, https://assets.website-files.com/5d016609a151693900497381/5d1f7a94fd3194c9ef4637c4_Wave%20test.png 1920w" 
            sizes=(max-width: 1920px) 100vw, 1920px" />
        }
    }
</style>
```

I expected the png image to at least show up I think I put it in right, but nothing is showing. I am not familiar with html/css which is why I was doing this in webflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the browser is IE in JavaScript, if IE then clear the svg and show the image. If not IE then show the svg. And you should use [background-image](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) in css when you want to show an image:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
            /* IE10+ specific styles go here */
            body {
                background-image: url(https://assets.website-files.com/5d016609a151693900497381/5d1f7a94fd3194c9ef4637c4_Wave%20test.png)
            }
        }
```

I also made a demo which you can refer to:

```js
//check if the broswer is IE
if (!!window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject" in window) { document.body.innerHTML = "";}
```

```css
body {
            font: 1.25em sans-serif;
            background-color: white;
        }

        #isi-wave #wave {
            -webkit-animation: moveWave 4s linear 0s infinite;
            animation: moveWave 4s linear 0s infinite;
        }

        #isi-wave #bubble_1 {
            -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 220px);
            -ms-transform: translate(0px, 220px);
            transform: translate(0px, 220px);
            -webkit-animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -1.8s infinite alternate;
            animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -1.8s infinite alternate;
        }

        #isi-wave #bubble_2 {
            -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 200px);
            -ms-transform: translate(0px, 200px);
            transform: translate(0px, 200px);
            -webkit-animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -2.28s infinite alternate;
            animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -2.28s infinite alternate;
        }

        #isi-wave #bubble_3 {
            -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 230px);
            -ms-transform: translate(0px, 230px);
            transform: translate(0px, 230px);
            -webkit-animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -3.2s infinite alternate;
            animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -3.2s infinite alternate;
        }

        #isi-wave #bubble_4 {
            -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 210px);
            -ms-transform: translate(0px, 210px);
            transform: translate(0px, 210px);
            -webkit-animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -3.8s infinite alternate;
            animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -3.8s infinite alternate;
        }

        #isi-wave #bubble_5 {
            -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 210px);
            -ms-transform: translate(0px, 210px);
            transform: translate(0px, 210px);
            -webkit-animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -0.92s infinite alternate;
            animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -0.92s infinite alternate;
        }

        #isi-wave #bubble_6 {
            -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 210px);
            -ms-transform: translate(0px, 210px);
            transform: translate(0px, 210px);
            -webkit-animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -1.32s infinite alternate;
            animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -1.32s infinite alternate;
        }

        #isi-wave #bubble_7 {
            -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 220px);
            -ms-transform: translate(0px, 220px);
            transform: translate(0px, 220px);
            -webkit-animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -2.04s infinite alternate;
            animation: moveIn 2s ease-in-out -2.04s infinite alternate;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes moveIn {
            to {
                -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
                transform: translate(0px, 0px);
            }
        }

        @keyframes moveIn {
            to {
                -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
                transform: translate(0px, 0px);
            }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes moveWave {
            to {
                -webkit-transform: translate(-1495.81px, 0px);
                transform: translate(-1495.81px, 0px);
            }
        }

        @keyframes moveWave {
            to {
                -webkit-transform: translate(-1495.81px, 0px);
                transform: translate(-1495.81px, 0px);
            }
        }

        @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
            /* IE10+ specific styles go here */
            body {
                background-image: url(https://assets.website-files.com/5d016609a151693900497381/5d1f7a94fd3194c9ef4637c4_Wave%20test.png)
            }
        }
```

```html
<div>
        <svg id="isi-wave" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="519 0 2022 1225.25"> <g id="wave"> <path d="M5983.25,234v991.28H0V233.7c8.66.74,17.26,1.13,26,1.52l.23.18C209.57,244,520.63,39,785.09,39c242.62,0,530.06,179.27,710.72,195v-.27c8.66.74,17.26,1.13,26,1.52l.23.18C1705.39,244,2016.44,39,2280.9,39c242.62,0,530.06,179.27,710.72,195v-.27c8.67.74,17.26,1.13,26,1.52l.23.18C3201.2,244,3512.26,39,3776.71,39c242.62,0,530.07,179.27,710.72,195v-.27c8.66.74,17.26,1.13,26,1.52l.23.18C4697,244,5008.07,39,5272.53,39,5515.15,39,5802.6,218.26,5983.25,234Z" fill="#00a6dd" /> <path d="M5983.25,187.32v51C5707.9,230.8,5516.38,86.11,5214.88,86.11c-237.08,0-397.67,115.57-615.18,145-9.24,1.23-18.56,2.35-28,3.23-18.87,1.85-38.17,3-58,3.35h-.23c-30.14.56-21.88.69-26,.62v0c-275.35-7.47-466.86-152.16-768.37-152.16-237.07,0-397.66,115.57-615.17,145-9.25,1.23-18.57,2.35-28,3.23-18.87,1.85-38.16,3-58,3.35h-.23c-30.13.56-21.88.69-25.95.62v0c-275.35-7.47-466.87-152.16-768.37-152.16-237.07,0-397.67,115.57-615.18,145-9.24,1.23-18.56,2.35-28,3.23-18.87,1.85-38.17,3-58,3.35h-.23c-30.13.56-21.88.69-26,.62C1220.45,230.8,1028.94,86.11,727.44,86.11c-237.08,0-397.67,115.57-615.18,145-9.24,1.23-18.56,2.35-28,3.23-18.87,1.85-38.16,3-58,3.35H26c-30.14.56-21.89.69-26,.62v-51c35.7,6.16,50.4,9.7,110.6,9.7C276.1,197,592.14,0,841.93,0c218.51,0,473.38,146.92,653.88,187.32,35.7,6.16,50.4,9.7,110.6,9.7C1771.91,197,2088,0,2337.74,0c218.51,0,473.38,146.92,653.88,187.32h0c35.7,6.16,50.4,9.7,110.6,9.7,165.5,0,481.54-197,731.32-197,218.52,0,473.38,146.92,653.88,187.32v0c35.7,6.16,50.4,9.7,110.6,9.7,165.5,0,481.54-197,731.33-197C5547.88,0,5802.75,146.92,5983.25,187.32Z" fill="#0045ab" /> </g> <g id="bubbles"> <circle id="bubble_1" data-name="bubble 1" cx="707.51" cy="109.89" r="70.69" fill="#fff" opacity="0.57" /> <circle id="bubble_2" data-name="bubble 2" cx="906.53" cy="83.33" r="49.13" fill="#fff" opacity="0.4" /> <circle id="bubble_3" data-name="bubble 3" cx="1267.49" cy="128.73" r="101.27" fill="#fff" opacity="0.35" /> <circle id="bubble_4" data-name="bubble 4" cx="1528.18" cy="88.09" r="61.16" fill="#fff" opacity="0.65" /> <circle id="bubble_5" data-name="bubble 5" cx="1892.64" cy="175.38" r="128.84" fill="#fff" opacity="0.52" /> <circle id="bubble_6" data-name="bubble 6" cx="2081.9" cy="83.86" r="44.87" fill="#fff" opacity="0.56" /> <circle id="bubble_7" data-name="bubble 7" cx="2339.83" cy="103.63" r="76.7" fill="#fff" opacity="0.7" /> </g> </svg>
</div>
```